# Applescript Syntax Error "Expected “else”, etc. but found end of script."

Tags: syntax, applescript

I am having trouble with this in applescript:

```
display dialog "Open Which Application" buttons {"Chrome", "AppleScript", "Textedit"} 
set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
if the button_pressed is "Chrome" then
Open application "Google Chrome"-- action for 1st button goes here
if the button_pressed is "Applescript" then
Open application "Applescript Editor"-- action for 2nd button goes here
if the button_pressed is "Textedit" then
Open application "Textedit"-- action for 3rd button goes here
end
```

It keeps saying SYNTAX ERROR: Expected “else”, etc. but found end of script.

What should I do

Answer (score 0):

You have three `if` statements, but you only `end` one of them.

What you probably want here is `else if`:

```
display dialog "Open Which Application" buttons {"Chrome", "AppleScript", "Textedit"}
set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
if the button_pressed is "Chrome" then
    open application "Google Chrome" -- action for 1st button goes here
else if the button_pressed is "Applescript" then
    open application "AppleScript Editor" -- action for 2nd button goes here
else if the button_pressed is "Textedit" then
    open application "TextEdit" -- action for 3rd button goes here
end if
```

(Also, you're really supposed to use `end if`, not just `end`, but AppleScript Editor will fix that for you.)

Alternatively, you could `end` each one:

```
display dialog "Open Which Application" buttons {"Chrome", "AppleScript", "Textedit"}
set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
if the button_pressed is "Chrome" then
    open application "Google Chrome" -- action for 1st button goes here
end if
if the button_pressed is "Applescript" then
    open application "AppleScript Editor" -- action for 2nd button goes here
end if
if the button_pressed is "Textedit" then
    open application "TextEdit" -- action for 3rd button goes here
end if
```

However, the cases are obviously mutually exclusive, so there's not reason not to use `else if` instead.

If it helps, type the lines in one by one and see how AppleScript Editor is indenting them:

```
display dialog "Open Which Application" buttons {"Chrome", "AppleScript", "Textedit"} 
set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
if the button_pressed is "Chrome" then
    Open application "Google Chrome"-- action for 1st button goes here
    if the button_pressed is "Applescript" then
        Open application "Applescript Editor"-- action for 2nd button goes here
        if the button_pressed is "Textedit" then
            Open application "Textedit"-- action for 3rd button goes here
        end
```

That should make it obvious what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
display dialog "Open Which Application" buttons {"Chrome", "AppleScript", "Textedit"}
set the button_pressed to the button returned of the result
if the button_pressed is "Chrome" then tell application "Google Chrome" to activate -- action for 1st button goes here 
if the button_pressed is "Applescript" then tell application "AppleScript Editor" to activate -- action for 2nd button goes here 
if the button_pressed is "Textedit" then tell application "TextEdit" to activate -- action for 3rd button goes here end
```